# Transit visa to the UK en route to the USA

Tags: air-travel

I have booked a ticket with British airways as follows.

- April 28, 2018 Hyderabad to London Heathrow.
- May 2, 2018 London Heathrow to Boston.

Do I need a transit visa to get into London? If yes, what is the procedure and what documents are required? Kindly advise. I have a valid US visa and a valid passport.

Comment: As you'll be spending several days in the UK, a transit visa will not suffice.  You need a Standard Visitor visa.

Comment: @MadHatter but the described itinerary is not actually a layover.

Comment: British Airways offer that route on that date with as little as 5 hours connection time. With a stay of several days, you would be a visitor to the UK, not a transit passenger. As you already have onward travel plans and a USA visa you should have no trouble getting a UK visit visa, but you should apply in advance.

Comment: Sorry, you are all (of course) right.  I put too much faith in the title of the question, and failed to realise the entire premiss was faulty.

Answer (score 2):

> **April 28, 2018 - May 2, 2018**
>
> Do I need a transit visa to get into London?

No, **You need a standard visitor visa** for that long a transit.

> Apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you’ll be going through UK border control but leaving the UK within 48 hours

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa)

However if your stay in the UK was for less than 48 hours and given the fact that you hold a visa for and are travelling to the USA you were eligible for a **transit without a visa**